# vim-go/synstastic Errors not automatically displaying on save

Tags: vim, go, syntastic

I noticed that when I save a file and I have a syntax error in my code, the error quickfix window does not automatically appear. I recently rebuilt my system and simply copied over my `.vim/` directory along with the same `.vimrc`file. I've done this before and have never had any issues. However, if I manually enter `:GoErrCheck` or `GoBuild`, the window shows up. What gives?

Here is my .vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
syntax on                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
filetype plugin indent on                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

set nu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
set completeopt-=preview                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
set encoding=utf-8              " Set default encoding to UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                               
set autoread                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
set laststatus=2                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
set noswapfile               " Don't use swapfile                                                                                                                                                                                             
set nobackup " Don't create annoying backup files                                                                                                                                                                                             
"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
nmap <Leader>t :TagbarToggle<CR>                                                                                                                                                                                                              

autocmd FileType qf wincmd J                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
"CtrlP Settings                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
let g:ctrlp_show_hidden = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                       

let g:go_highlight_functions = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                              
let g:go_highlight_methods = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                
let g:go_highlight_fields = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
let g:go_highlight_structs = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                
let g:go_highlight_interfaces = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                             
let g:go_highlight_operators = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                              
let g:go_highlight_build_constraints = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
let g:molokai_original = 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                    


let mapleader=","                                                                                                                                                                                                              
colorscheme molokai
```

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the vim-go repo as SO isn't geared for "tooling" questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readme file in [`vim-go`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go#using-with-syntastic) explains its usage with `syantastic`

> Sometimes when using both vim-go and syntastic Vim will start lagging while saving and opening files. The following fixes this:
>
> ```
> let g:syntastic_go_checkers = ['golint', 'govet', 'errcheck']
> let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active', 'passive_filetypes': ['go'] }
> ```
>
> Another issue with vim-go and syntastic is that the location list window that contains the output of commands such as :GoBuild and :GoTest might not appear. To resolve this:
>
> ```
> let g:go_list_type = "quickfix"
> ```

In [this issue](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/886)

One recommendation is to remove the lines

```
let g:syntastic_go_checkers = ['golint', 'govet', 'errcheck']
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active', 'passive_filetypes':
```

and use

```
let g:syntastic_go_checkers = ['govet', 'errcheck', 'go']
```

instead

Comment: Beware that support for Go checkers in syntastic [is going away](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1759).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about errors shown by syntastic, this issue is probably similar to the one discussed here : [vim-go with syntastic](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/848)

> Synastic doesn't check Go files on save by default (anymore). Add this
>   to your `.vimrc` to make that happen:
>
> `let g:syntastic_go_checkers = ['go']`